# Parasolid viewer in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, 3d, cad

I would like to a add an Parasolid (.x_t) viewer into my Winforms application. The user just needs to view the Parasolid-Model be able to rotate it.

Unfortunatly I have no idea how to implement it. Hopfully someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

[Parasolid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasolid) is a proprietary file format. You need to purchase a license from Siemens to translate *.x_t files to geometric data (normally using a .NET wrapper on unmanaged C++ library), then you need a CAD control for WinForms to display it on screen.